# Java font family name discrepancy

Tags: java, fonts

On my WinXP box under JDK6, the following code:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

public class TestFontFamily
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for( String s : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames() )
        {
            Font f = Font.decode(s);
            if( f != null && !s.equals(f.getFamily()) )
                System.out.println(String.format("%-20s %s", s, f));
        }
    }
}
```

prints the following list:

```
Bauhaus 93           java.awt.Font[family=Dialog,name=Bauhaus,style=plain,size=93]
Bookshelf Symbol 7   java.awt.Font[family=Dialog,name=Bookshelf Symbol,style=plain,size=7]
Britannic Bold       java.awt.Font[family=Dialog,name=Britannic,style=bold,size=12]
Harlow Solid Italic  java.awt.Font[family=Dialog,name=Harlow Solid,style=italic,size=12]
Modern No. 20        java.awt.Font[family=Dialog,name=Modern No.,style=plain,size=20]
Wingdings 2          java.awt.Font[family=Wingdings,name=Wingdings,style=plain,size=2]
Wingdings 3          java.awt.Font[family=Wingdings,name=Wingdings,style=plain,size=3]
```

So the question is why font family name from `Font#decode` is different? And which one should I use?

It seems both have problems: `getAvailableFontFamilyNames()` includes style/size, and what I get from `Font#decode` may have wrong family/name.

A bonus question is then: **What is a reliable way to get a list of fonts?**

The following code does not work either, as some fonts' "name" differs from "family name", *e.g.* the family name of "Berlin Sans FB Demi Bold" is "Berlin Sans FB Demi".

```
for( Font f : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts() )
{
    if( f.getFamily().equals(f.getName()) )
        System.out.println(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I wonder what badge I may get for answering my own tumbleweed question.)

I found that `Font.decode(s + " plain")` gives me fonts with the right family names.